# Hypoellipticity of a heat-like parabolic operator on Riemannian manifolds - reference request

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemannian-geometry, elliptic-pde, differential-operators, parabolic-pde

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold and $L$ be a differential operator on $M$, with smooth coefficients, such that its symbol be $g$ (a "generalized Laplacian").

> Where can I find proved that the operator $\partial_t - L$ on $(0, \infty) \times M$ is hypoelliptic?

I am not interested in a proof, I can prove it myself (by expressing $L$ in coordinates, collecting the principal terms and then using any of the available theorems in the literature - for instance [S. Mizohata, "Hypoellipticité des équations paraboliques"](https://eudml.org/doc/urn:eudml:doc:86918), but I believe that this one is overkill). I want to save space in an article that I am working on, in which this hypoellipticity is a just side matter (a "bonus"), and just cite a reference.

Comment: Is it not a direct application of the standard elliptic regularity theorem? It seems obvious that $L$ is an elliptic operator in any coordinate chart.

Comment: @NateEldredge: $L$ is indeed elliptic, but I am asking about the parabolic operator $\partial_t - L$, and I don't know how elliptic regularity helps.